Component appears on screen for a second even though the state is "false"
I am going to hide a component if a state is false. It does work but when I refresh the page it appears on the screen for a second!
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const [showBanner, setShowBanner] = useState((state) => {
    console.log(4, window.localStorage.getItem("MY_APP_STATE"));
    return window.localStorage.getItem("MY_APP_STATE") ?? true;
  });

  useEffect(() => {
    const data = window.localStorage.getItem("MY_APP_STATE");
    console.log(1, data);
    if (data !== null) setShowBanner(JSON.parse(data));
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(2, showBanner);
    window.localStorage.setItem("MY_APP_STATE", JSON.stringify(showBanner));
  }, [showBanner]);

  console.log(3, showBanner);
  return (
    <div>
      {console.log(5, showBanner)}
      <main>
        {showBanner && (
          <div>
            Hello
            <button onClick={() => setShowBanner(false)}>Hide</button>
          </div>
        )}
      </main>
    </div>
  );
}

After clicking on the hide button, "console.log(5, showBanner)" shows false but still we see the "Hello" for a second.

Have you considered defaulting to false and then updating from storage? There's going to be a delay otherwise. You're already doing the storage check in useEffect, so I'm not sure why you'd do it twice.
